# Retrieve a numeric ID from a Model instance just created

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

From google documentation:

"A model instance's key includes the instance's entity kind along with a unique identifier. The identifier may be either a key name string, assigned explicitly by the application when the instance is created, or an integer numeric ID, assigned automatically by App Engine when the instance is written (put) to the Datastore. "

so in the example:

```
name = "John"
idd = 11
person = Person(name, idd)
person.put()
```

How do i get the "integer numeric ID, assigned automatically by App Engine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using ndb put() returns the new key... call the id function on the key:

```
name = "John"
idd = 11
person = Person(name, idd)
new_key = person.put()
auto_assigned_id = new_key.id()
```

from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities :

> To store the object as a persistent entity in the Datastore, use the
>   put() method. This returns a key for retrieving the entity from the
>   Datastore later:
>
> `sandy_key = sandy.put()`

and:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_id

Comment: TypeError: 'Key' object is not callable

Comment: The main problem here is getting the ID from the Key

Comment: @mFontoura first you need to save it

Comment: @mFontoura sorry had a typo there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the

```
print person.id()
```

or if you have provided the unique identifuer

```
print person.id_or_name()
```

Also the put() method returns the key

```
key = person.put()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: My problem is getting the ID from the Key